# How to make tor browser work with the system tor service rather than the tor service provided with the browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, browsers

How to make tor browser work with the system tor service rather than the tor service provided with the browser.

Certain files in the `Browser` folder must be changed.

---

PS: I start the tor service  on Linux with

```
# service tor start
```

Answer (score 2):

From the guide I wrote, available on the Tor Project wiki [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorBrowserBundleSAQ):

Add or edit the following lines in your torrc:

```
# add these flags to SocksPort to act like Tor Browser
SocksPort 9050 IPv6Traffic PreferIPv6 KeepAliveIsolateSOCKSAuth
ControlPort 9051
# only add these if they're *not* already defined in /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc
# i.e. if you're not using debian, ubuntu or one of their derivatives
#CookieAuthentication 1
#CookieAuthFile /var/run/tor/control.authcookie
#CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
```

Now reload Tor

```
sudo service tor reload
```

Then add your user to the group that the tor daemon runs as, on debian, ubuntu and similar this is `debian-tor`

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-tor $USER
```

This will require a full log out and back in to take effect.

Now we need to add some environment variables that Tor Button and Tor Launcher will respect. Create a file called somthing like `/etc/profile.d/99_tb.sh` and add the following to it:

```
# Use system daemon socks port
export TOR_SOCKS_PORT=9050
# Use system daemon control port
export TOR_CONTROL_PORT=9051
# Don't launch a second tor instance, and don't take ownership of it.
export TOR_SKIP_LAUNCH=1
# Tell it where to find the control auth cookie
export TOR_CONTROL_COOKIE_AUTH_FILE=/var/run/tor/control.authcookie
```

This will also require a full log out and back in to take effect.

Now when you launch Tor Browser, it should use the local tor daemon instance instead of starting it's own.

Comment: Isn't it easier to disable the TorButton and TorLauncher extensions in the browser and set up the proxy via preferences?

Comment: deleting the addons is uglier, more annoying (no NEWNYM, New Tor Circuit, Security Slider) and requires reapplication on new installs, these tweaks persist.

Comment: What are the differences on using Tor systemd service? Is there any advantages on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I realize the more recent versions of tor browser already contain the instructions (edit: they are different from the ones given in the tor wiki, which works for tor browser 5.x). For the benefit of other users, I have edited the [tor wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorBrowserBundleSAQ) ([onion](http://ea5faa5po25cf7fb.onion/projects/tor/wiki/TorBrowserBundleSAQ)) to include it. To quote it verbatim:

> ## How do I make Tor Browser 7.x (may work for later versions) use the tor that is already running on the system?
>
> See the section **Using a system-installed Tor process with Tor Browser** in the file `$TB_INST_DIR/Browser/start-tor-browser` where `$TB_INST_DIR` is your tor browser installation directory (e.g. `tor-browser_en-US`) for instructions. Alternatively, you can view them ​​[online](https://gitweb.torproject.org/builders/tor-browser-bundle.git/tree/RelativeLink/start-tor-browser) ([​onion](http://jqs44zhtxl2uo6gk.onion/builders/tor-browser-bundle.git/tree/RelativeLink/start-tor-browser)). Be careful, the online version is on the master branch, which may be too new for your tor browser. When in doubt, follow the one coming with your tor browser.